# Highchart export filename with special characters

Tags: highcharts, shiny, shiny-server

I am using Highcharts to render plots within ShinyServer.  Everything works well on Firefox but in Chrome the export chocks on duplicate headers; this is because the [filename contains commas](https://helpdesk.egnyte.com/hc/en-us/articles/201637494-What-is-the-Duplicate-Headers-Warning-).

Is there a way to properly escape the filename within highcharts or Shiny?  The recommendation is to double quote the filename but I only pass the first part of the name to highcharts and not the extension so I cannot double quote the whole string in Shiny.  I have access to the highcharts server so I could modify that if I knew where to look.

I realise the simple solutions are

1. Not to put commas in the filename or
2. Not to use chrome,

**but**

1. Sooner or later I will have to use a special character of some sort and
2. Chrome is just adhering more strictly to safe practices and other browsers will follow suite one day.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap exporting function by [API](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/extending-highcharts/extending-highcharts) and then in this part, escape / modify name.

```
Highcharts.post(options.url, {
        filename: options.filename || 'chart',
        type: options.type,
        width: options.width || 0, // IE8 fails to post undefined correctly, so use 0
        scale: options.scale || 2,
        svg: svg
}, options.formAttributes);
```